# Disable checkbox if empty record

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

What I have here is disabling checkbox if column is empty. I have `pr` column and if that column is empty checkbox is disabled. I also have dropdown that if I select it hides the other link.

But the real problem on this is when I select add button, only the empty column should allowed to check or the column that has a value will be disable. And if I select remove/edit all column that has a value should only be checked.

Help please?

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
function setCheckboxes3(act) {
    $('.checkbox').not(':disabled').prop('checked', act == 1 ? true : false);
}
</script>
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.button.edit, a.button.remove, a.button.add').click(function () {
        if ($('input[name="checkbox[]"]:checked').length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('edit')) {
            if (!confirm('Edit this Record(s)?')) {
                return
            }
        } else /*if ($(this).hasClass('remove')) */{
            if (!confirm('WARNING !!! All Purchase Order that included in this Record(s) will be deleted.')) {
                return
            }
        }

        var frm = document.myform;
        if ($(this).hasClass('edit')) {
            frm.action = 'editpr.php';
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('add')) {
            frm.action = 'addmulpr.php';
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('remove')) {
                if (!confirm('Are you sure want to continue?')) {
                return
            }
        }
        frm.submit();
    });
});
</script>

<select id="button1">
<option value="add" selected="selected">Add</option>
<option value="edit">Edit</option>
<option value="delete">Delete</option>
</select>
<?php
<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['id'] . '"'.($row['pr'] == ""?"disabled ":"").' style="cursor:pointer;" class="checkbox"></td> ?>

  <a class="button add buttons" style="cursor:pointer;"><span><b>Add Purchase Request</b></span></a>
  <a id="edit" class="button edit buttons" style="cursor:pointer;"><span><b>Edit Purchase Request</b></span></a>
  <a id="remove"class="button remove buttons" style="cursor:pointer;" name="remove"><span><b>Remove Purchase Request</b></span></a> 
  <input type='hidden' class='button' name='remove'/>
  <a href="javascript:setCheckboxes3(true);" class="button chkmenu"><span><b>Check All</b></span></a>
  <a href="javascript:setCheckboxes3(false);" class="button chkmenu"><span><b>Uncheck All</b></span></a>
<script>
$('#button1').change(function () {
    var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
    $('a.buttons').eq(index).show().siblings('a.buttons').hide();
}).change();
</script>
```

Comment: Sidenote: This `id="checkbox[]"` should not have brackets; only `name="checkbox[]"`

Comment: You're welcome. Plus, this line `<?php
<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['id'] . '"'.($row['pr'] == ""?"disabled ":"").' style="cursor:pointer;" class="checkbox"></td> ?>` that's incorrect. You need to echo what's inside `<?php ... ?>` that will throw an error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I echo it, I just cut it to make it short.

Answer (score -1):

See id naming convention ..[Limit to jQuery id strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619929/limit-to-jquery-id-strings)

```
ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number  of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
```

Comment: That is not from the jquery docs, it's the id spec for HTML4. Jquery only gets fussy with colons and periods and only when not escaped in the selector.